# Question re rules of this site

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Why rules of this site, according to which questions are handled by moderators (evaluated, put on hold and get closed ), are constructed that way, that they are favoring trivialization and oversimplification of the philosophy ?

PS Since this site allows only questions and disallows critical statements - I am dressing my critique into the veiled clothes of the question ...

PPS Philosophy, by definition, is: "The study of the fundamental nature of knowledge, reality, and existence".

Philosophy utilizes abstraction ("formation of recognizing some set of common features in individual phenomena, and on that basis forming a concept of that feature") as one of its most important tools.

Philosophy, therefore, is highly sophisticated and complicated thought process and it deals with very broad and deep problems.

Philosophy differs from other disciplines, which have one established commonly recognized academic approach. Instead of dominating, commonly recognized approach, - there are many contradicting philosophical views and assumptions, and each of them has the right to exist and be discussed.

That is why philosophical questions could not be fit into Procrustean bed of set of narrow rules and be put on hold and closed as "too broad", "opinion based", "based on personal philosophy", etc.

Comment: I am asking to answer my clearly formulated question.

Comment: Dear Alex, for a more constructive discussion, it would be helpful if you could link to a specific question or two, of yours or someone else's, that has (or have) been closed solely by a moderator (or collectively by a group of us, ordinary participants) in a way that favors "trivialization and oversimplification" of whatever you think philosophy is. On many occasions a question that is closed is re-opened, mostly because of helpful edits by the OP and/or other participants. I look forward to your examples. If that doesn't interest you, best of luck with your studies.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan -in this question I am not criticizing actions of people, I am criticizing the RULES of this site. Philosophy differs from other disciplines, which have one established commonly recognized academic approach. Instead of dominating, commonly recognized approach, - there are many contradicting philosophical views and assumptions, and each of them has the right to exist and be discussed. That is why philosophical questions could not be fit into Procrustean bed of set of narrow rules and be put on hold and closed as "too broad", "opinion based", "based on personal philosophy", etc.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan As far as actions of individual moderators - I filed official complaint on actions of "stoicfury" to the administration of this site and I am awaiting response from those people - but out of ethical reasons I don't want to bring the issue of his behavior and actions into the public discussion.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking: "By what set of rules are questions evaluated in order to determine whether they are fit for this site?"

In that case, you can refer to these guidelines which were written by the people that run this website:

## [What topics can I ask about here?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

## [How do I ask a good question?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

## [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: No - you did NOT understand my question correctly. I am asking specifically - why the rules, as they are formulated, are favoring trivialization and oversimplification of the philosophy as an discipline of science ...

Comment: @Alex We also have a [community FAQ](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/362/faq-for-philosophy-se) that might help give a sense of what the discussions on meta have been like that may have informed the on-topic line, what we consider constructive, etc.

Comment: Why did you accept my answer if I answered the wrong question? At any rate, your English is difficult for me (and perhaps others) to understand; perhaps you can type it into translate.google.com in your native tongue and get an English translation?

Comment: @Joseph Weissman - I see ... restrictive rules are everywhere - even on meta ...  "Resistance is futile. You will be assimilated"

Comment: @alex the questions and answers community members contribute on meta is *how* the community formulates it's own rules; I'm not really sure what you're saying here

Comment: @JosephWeissman - Borg was also a community with restrictive rules ... Even US constitution has an option for amendments - and this community should have an option in its rules for amending its rules ... And there should be an avenue to propose and discuss such amendments ...

Comment: Come on - i said it clearly enough, please do not play such game ;-). Please also see my latest comment in reply to Joseph Weissman.

Comment: That avenue *is meta*

Comment: @JosephWeissman - this meta ?

Comment: @Alex - Seriously?

Comment: I am serious - you are not. You should drop this condescending tone in talking to anyone (me included).

Comment: If you are perceiving a tone of condescension, it is only in your mind. Rest assured that I have ambitions in life beyond condescending strangers on the internet. I — like you — simply enjoy philosophy and I am grateful that I am allowed to do everything I can to help cultivate this community. :) That said, you are being difficult with us. I'm not sure if it's the language-barrier, ignorance, arrogance, or a combination thereof, but there's an issue with our communication. I still don't know what this question is about; please make it intelligible...

Comment: "us" - this alone speaks for itself ... It also appears that you are using your mods credentials for personal vengeance ...

Comment: Yes, you caught me. I closed your question out of revenge because I am mad at you... Please, I don't know if you are trolling or what but I've been nothing but patient with you. Your question was answered, but you said it was not the answer you were looking for, which means your question is obviously unclear (hence why no one else attempted to answer). Further, your edits admit that you don't actually have a question at all, you just want to (unintelligibly) vent your frustration (*"I am dressing my statement into the veiled clothes of the question ..."*). That's why this was closed.